# Optimize multiple replacement based on condition per ID

Tags: r, replace

Which is the fastest way to do this? I have many 'value' columns (>100) in which I have to replace values when 'valueAux' is zero.
'Value1' column should be set to zero always that 'value1Aux' (for the same row) is zero

Original data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
 value1 = c(23, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 8, 12),
   value2 = c(0, 12, 56, 7, 8, 1, 8, 12),
  value1aux = c(0, 0, 89, 65, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  value2aux = c (1,1,0,0,4,15,67,12))
```

Result desired data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
 value1 = c(0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 12),
   value2 = c(0, 12, 0, 0, 8, 1, 8, 12),
  value1aux = c(0, 0, 89, 65, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  value2aux = c (1,1,0,0,4,15,67,12))
```

Code to optimize:

```
names <- colnames(df[2:3])
names2 <- colnames(df[4:5])
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
df[i,names] <- replace (df[i,names], df[i,names2] == 0, 0)}
```

Comment: What you have is fine, you can just remove the looping part. `df[,names] <- replace (df[,names], df[,names2] == 0, 0)`